# Trouble with levels on continuous bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, bar-chart

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
testSet <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04",
                                     "2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
                      yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), 
                      mo = c(07,08,09,10,11), 
                      da = c(02,03,04,05,06), 
                      plant = LETTERS[1:5], 
                      product = letters[26:22], 
                      rating = runif(5))
```

What I would like to do is plot 2 graphs using `ggplot2`.

The first would give me a dodged, continuous bar chart for all months that would have the product on the `x`, the ratings on the `y`, and the dates grouped and plotted on their respective products.

```
x = product

y = rating

Dodge = date
```

The second that I'm trying to create is a dodged, continuous bar chart for one month that would have the plant on the x, the ratings on the y, and the product grouped and plotted on their respective plants.

```
x = plant

y = rating

Dodge = product
```

I'm looking for an output that is very similar to this: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_bar-28.png but continuous.

I've had issues trying to figure out how the levels things works and haven't seen an example of a dodged, continuous chart.

Here is the code I have created so far:

```
testMean <- tapply(testSet$rating, list(testSet$mo), mean)

testLevels <- factor(levels(testSet$product,testSet$mo), 
                  levels = levels(testSet$product,testSet$mo))

qplot(testLevels, aes(testMean, fill=cut)) +
          geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

This is what the ggplot2 site says about creating a continuous bar chart, but it doesn't say anything about how to do it with multiple graphs overlayed on top of each other and then dodged, like in the one I linked to earlier. Here is their code:

```
meanprice <- tapply(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, mean)

cut <- factor(levels(diamonds$cut), levels = levels(diamonds$cut))
qplot(cut, meanprice)
```

I appreciate the help, guys!

Comment: hi there, have you tested the code you posted?  I am not sure what you are doing there with the `levels()`, but it does not make sense.  What were you hoping for `testLevels` to be?    Also, it appears you are confusing `data.table` with `data.frame`

Comment: I added new information to the posting as well. Basically, that's how the ggplot2 site has that specific graph set up. However, it is only doing one graph, whereas I want to overlay all of the graphs onto one graph.

Comment: And the code I posted does not work. I get a failure when creating testLevels.

Comment: @black_sheep07 your question is not clear. Could you provide a better dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the diamonds built in data set to get my question answered. All the thanks in the world to @carloscinelli for his assistance.

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(diamonds)[,list(mean_carat=mean(carat)), by=c('cut', 'color')]
```

Thanks!